# dealing with "NA" as both missing value and ordinal feature value

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have a `.txt` dataset with about 80 features, where it appears that `"NA"` is used as both an indicator of a missing value, as well as an actual value for particular ordinal string features, such as:

[image]

What is the best way to handle this?

By default, pandas converts these `"NA"` values to `"nan"`. I read how to stop this by removing `"NA"` from the list `na_vals` like so:

```
na_vals = ['-1.#IND', '1.#QNAN', '1.#IND', '-1.#QNAN', '#N/A', 'N/A', 'NA', '#NA', 'NULL', 'NaN', '-NaN', 'nan', '-nan']
na_vals.remove("NA")
data = pd.read_table('data/AmesHousing.txt', delimiter="\t", keep_default_na=False, na_values=na_vals)
```

But then, should I manually replace `"NA"` values with `"nan"` for each feature for which `"NA"` is not a possible value? If so, how is this done? If not, what's a better way of doing this? Thanks!

**Edit**: I should clarify, I've made the assumption that `"NA"` is also used for missing values, because if I remove `"NA"` from the `na_values` list, `data.isnull().sum().sum()` returns `0`. So I guess either my assumption is correct or there are actually no missing values in the entire dataset. I'm not sure how to determine which of these is true. [The dataset description page can be found here.](https://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v19n3/decock/DataDocumentation.txt)

Comment: I don't think it can be done easily unless you have a clear algorithm, which would can distinguish which `NA` is `No Basement` and which one is `NaN`. If you can use different value for showing `NaN` - then you can easily solve this problem. As a last resort you can try to build a Neural Network and train it, but i'm not sure it worth it... ;-)

Comment: @MaxU my solution involves a neural net with a hidden layer of length zero (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Jupyter` I use the `%%writefile` magic to set up a test file.  This isn't necessary if you already have a file.

```
%%writefile test.csv
col1,col2,col3
Ex,1.,2.
Gd,3.,4.
TA,5.,NA
NA,6.,7.
```

**Solution**
parse twice, requires that I know the name of columns with legitimate `'NA'` values.  Make sure to populate the list with the column names that are relevant to you.

```
cols_with_legit_NA = ['col1']

legit_df = pd.read_csv(
    'test.csv',
     usecols=cols_with_legit_NA,
     keep_default_na=False
)
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv').assign(**legit_df)

df

  col1  col2  col3
0   Ex   1.0   2.0
1   Gd   3.0   4.0
2   TA   5.0   NaN
3   NA   6.0   7.0
```

Comment: you used `%%writefile` instead of `%%writefill` and I accidentally deleted my dataset by blindly copying, good thing I have a backup ;p

Comment: If you have `test.csv` already... choose a different file name (-:

Comment: Hmm okay so seems the typo was the reverse of what I expected, what does the first code block accomplish?

Comment: I'm setting up a test file to demonstrate the concept.  Otherwise, remove that block and just replace `test.csv` with the name of your file.  **And** populate the list of column names with column names that are relevant to you.